# Sentences ending with a hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink, conventions

This questions always stumps me for a couple of seconds every time I come across it so in the interest of saving a couple of minutes of thinking over the duration of my web development career:

If you have a sentence that ends with a hyperlink, like so:

> If you want to get in contact, [find our contact
>   details here.](/contactus)

Should I end the sentence with the full stop inside the anchor or outside of it?

Comment: Your example doesn't actually have a hyperlink :-)

Comment: Isn't this a grammar question?

Comment: @Celada Sorry, only internal SO links show up. Fixed now.

Comment: @Ghodmode A grammer question specifically related to HTML that is of interest to professional and enthusiast programmers I would have thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformulate the sentence, e.g. so that only “contact details” are link text. In fact, do you need anything else but “contact details” as a link?

In any case, leave the punctuation outside the link, as it is not logically part of the link text. A terminating period would look odd e.g. in a list of all links on the page (which some browsers are able to generate).

Punctuation as such does not matter much, but link text adequacy does: is the link text understandable even when taken out of context? Link texts are relevant to search engines, too, and should have informative, compact content.

Typographically, it may look slightly weird if a period at the end of a sentence is of different color than the preceding text and lacks underline though the preceding text is underlined. But this is a small price to pay

Answer (score 3):

Put any terminal punctutation (period, question mark, exclamation mark) outside the hyperlink.

See [Grammar Girl, episode 78](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/formatting_hyperlinks.aspx) for more.

Comment: Hmm, but it always looks ugly, especially with color variances.

Comment: @ajbeaven So you asked a question here, but you don't like the (correct) answer. Why bother asking :P

Comment: @PeeHaa Indeed. Its just what I think when I see it. Thanks for the link Bevan!

Answer (score 0):

I would treat this the same as with quotes, so, being Australian (same for UK), I would exclude the full stop from the link, while Americans include punctuation in quotes (even if it's not part of the quote). Australia/UK: This is a "quote". US: This is a "quote." I'm not sure whether this same principle can be applied to hyperlink conventions.

Having said that, however, I would recommend not using "here" as part of the link text. [Too many people use "click here" as a link](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%22click+here%22+link&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FQA%2FTips%2FnoClickHere&ei=CDQKT_vQG4aziQfoxaS-CQ&usg=AFQjCNGvU9HDw6MI1tzZ9w5b8Af4kMeVqQ&sig2=Fp4Nace7tCRQ-Z6CXHA-ew). Simply omitting the word "here" in your example should do.